# How to use Chai to ensure Promise throws Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

Currently when I have a promise that throws an error, in order to test that the correct error is thrown, I'm doing something like the following.

```
let result, error;
try {
    result = await myFunction();
} catch (e) {
    error = e;
}

expect(result).to.not.exist;
expect(error).to.eql(new Error("You must pass in a parameter."));
```

Whereas, if `myFunction` was not a promise or async function, I could do the following.

```
expect(() => myFunction()).to.throw(new Error("You must pass in a parameter."));
```

Is there a better way to check to see if an error is thrown for a promise/async function when using Mocha/Chai?

Comment: How about https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/

Answer (score 0):

You could use [chai-as-promised](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/)

Your code will be something like this (not tested) :

```
return expect(myFunction()).be.rejectedWith(Error, 'You must pass in a parameter.');
```